# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Prevent background notifications in javascript client

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a live score display website which is implemented with Google's channel API to push live score updates to the browser. Since Google is shutting down the channel API, I have to move to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

When I migrated to FCM, I had to add a service worker javascript file (firebase-messaging-sw.js). Whenever a score update is pushed to the browser, if the user is in another browser tab or the user has closed my web page tab, A notification appears to the user.

I don't need this notification and I want to disable it. Also, when user moves to another browser tab, I want to prevent the push message from going into the service worker and route it to my web page, so that when user returns to the tab again, the latest score is updated in the webpage.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you only need updates when the browser tab with the app is active, I'd recommend using something like the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) instead of FCM.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My web page displays scores of a single match a user has registered to, so I don't need to sync the scores of all matches to the browser. Is it possible to achieve this with Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: You found a solution or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a parameter (depends what you need to do) in the body of message like this:

```
$msg = [
  'title' => pushTitle,
  'body'=> pushBody,
  'icon'=> icon.png,
  'image'=> image.png,
  'active'=> 1
];
```

The above is PHP but is also working in the same way-idea in any programming language. If you use Firebase then you should use cloud functions.

then in your js file:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message', payload);

  if(payload.data.active == 1){
    return;
  }
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    image: payload.data.image
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

If I had your code(what did you have done until now) I would gave you an exact answer.
If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't find any official documentation about that but I've found a workaround, which is to set up your push notification as a data-only message (i.e., don't include a 'notification' field in the push request), and handle the creation of the notification object within the 'onBackgroundMessage' handler...

Note ` You have to handle mobile and web versions of the App differently as the IOS does not work if the field notification excludes